# SQLite Can't open — Meteor create app

Tags: macos, sqlite, meteor

I'm trying to create a new app with Meteor (this is the first time I've used it on this computer).

When I try and start a new app:

```
meteor create simple-todos
```

I'm getting the following error and creating the app fails:

```
{ [Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file]
stack: [Getter] }
```

And below that I get some other errors:

```
Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
    at Object.Future.wait (/Users/Jack/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.2l3p0l++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
```

I can't find other people having this same issue, so I'm a bit in the dark as to how to debug or fix. Pointers as to how to debug / fix this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It may be a permission error.

In order to fix this issue, you could try to adjust the permission by running this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.meteor
```

Comment: For me `Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file` showed up, when the directory (in which the SQLite file was located) didn't exist. So I needed to make sure that the directory is there before my SQL query builder (Knex.js) is accessing / creating the SQLite database.